# If I malloc(1) twice in a row, why do the values differ by 32?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

In C, if I run `malloc(1)` twice and then print out the two values casted to a `uintptr_t`, the values differ by 32. For example,

```
void * last = malloc(1);
void * next = malloc(1);
printf("orig %lu\n", ((uintptr_t)last));
printf("next %lu\n", ((uintptr_t)next));
```

prints out

```
orig 30572560
next 30572592
```

`malloc(size_t size)` allocates size bytes, according to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). I would expect the value to increase by 8 when I `malloc` one byte, then another. Why do they differ by 32 instead? Thanks!

Comment: not an ans but use `%p` to print the pointer.

Comment: I wanted the decimal representation, not the hex, which is why I didn't use %p

Answer (score 5):

This is actually implementation detail that will differ between different compilers/standard libriaries. In general, there is no guarantee that your subsequent `malloc` calls will return adjacent memory regions. Also note that each memory region is associated with additional metadata, including but not limited to region size (otherwise it wouldn't be possible to know how much memory to deallocate when `free` is run). This metadata is usually put inside of a allocated region, making it bigger than it was requested. There are some other factors that influence how much memory is actually allocated - memory alignment and "hole" finding algorithm used by your `malloc` implementation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc may not guarantee consecutive memory addresses.  It depends on the compiler.  Also note that memory accesses are done optimally at specific boundaries, such as four bytes (or eight bytes on other architectures), so if malloc did give consecutive memory addresses, it may insert padding to avoid byte-by-byte addressing.

Also print your pointers as such with `%p`, as opposed to integers.

Comment: With your reasoning, the difference would be 4, not 32 (the difference is not measured in *bits*).

Comment: @ktodisco: the value of the pointer remains the same, not affected by the format specifier.

Comment: @brokenfoot They will be printed differently.  Try it in a sample program.  For example, printing a pointer with `%p` I get `0x002E9390`, and with `%lu` I get `3052432`.  The format specifier does matter.  However, I was wrong about `malloc` giving subsequent aligned memory addresses, and will correct the answer.

Comment: @ktodisco: `%p` prints the hex value & `lu` the unsigned int. The value still remains the same. The decimal value of `0x002E9390`, I checked, is indeed `3052432`

Comment: @brokenfoot Yes.  I did *not* say that the values would be changed.  I said that they would be printed differently.  One in base 10, and the other in base 16.

Comment: Thanks. As others have hinted, I didn't use %p because I wanted an integer, not hex.

Answer (score 1):

Because memory allocators work on specified bounderies. On your case - its 32 bytes (not bits, bytes).

There is a nice technique called [pointer tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) that abuses it to save space. See this blog post to undertand how (basically - they save a state in the lower bits of the pointer, and before reading the content of the pointer they "zero" the LSB).

http://jkt.flaska.net/blog/Tagged_pointers__and_saving_memory_in_Trojita.html

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` guarantees to return a pointer to a block of *at least* the size you requested, with the proper alignment for storing any object of the size you requested or `NULL`.
How `malloc()` gets and parcels out those blocks is completely implementation defined within those boundaries, and you should not depend on it in any way.
Because `malloc()` has to store some bookkeeping data for `free()`, and must guarantee the alignment for bigger requests, your implementation in this instance somehow gave you blocks 32 bytes appart.

Aside: Subtracting pointers into different memory blocks is not allowed.
Also, your program is provokes undefined behavior by trying to print `uintptr_t`: The proper format specifier for that would be `PRIdPTR`.

Trivia: Making `free()` do nothing is a valid choice, which means the bookkeeping data can be omitted.

Comment: "supported", in your last sentence,  is not a good word. It may be supported and in most cases is but this behavior is implementation/architecture dependent and non standard.

Answer (score 0):

`Malloc` ensures the data is stored in contigous memory (may do some padding/alignment) only if you allocate some block in one call to `malloc`. Something like

```
char *p = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
```

Here the addresses of `p[0]` & `p[1]` will be contiguous.
But for:

```
char *p1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
char *p2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

There is no guarantee, it may/may not find contiguous memory to allocate blocks pointed to by `p1` & `p2`.